# How to use the Mysql query in Codeigniter joins?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter, I have an issue with MySQL query. I tried from my side but it's not getting my expected output.

After getting the answer from @tcadidot0, my issue got resolved but I have to use the below query with my joins.

```
SELECT A.* FROM tbl_payment_invoice A 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `bank_id`,MAX(`payment_invoice_date`) AS maxdt 
   FROM tbl_payment_invoice GROUP BY `bank_id`) B
ON A.`bank_id`=B.`bank_id` AND A.`payment_invoice_date`=B.`maxdt`;
```

Can you help me out how can I use it above query in this join `->join('tbl_payment_invoice','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_payment_invoice.bank_id','LEFT')`?

Final query

```
$result = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('tbl_lead')
                    ->join('tbl_bankdata','tbl_lead.c_id=tbl_bankdata.lead_id','LEFT')
                    ->join('tbl_bankname','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_bankdata.b_bankname')
                    ->join('tbl_payment_invoice','tbl_bankname.b_id=tbl_payment_invoice.bank_id','LEFT')
                    ->order_by('tbl_lead.date_of_created','DESC')
                    ->get()
                    ->result();
```

Should I need to use a subquery?

Comment: 1) When you use aggregate functions, you have to GROUP BY remaining columns in SELECT. 
Try this query:
select bank_id, max(payment_invoice), max(payment_invoice_date) as dateofadded from tbl_payment_invoice
group by bank_id;
Is it what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: @equi, I thought I can't use max(payment_invoice). can you help me with the second issue? How to use the same query in CodeIgniter? –

Comment: @Strawberry, I updated the question and descriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM tbl_payment_invoice A 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT `bank_id`,MAX(`payment_invoice_date`) AS maxdt 
   FROM tbl_payment_invoice GROUP BY `bank_id`) B
ON A.`bank_id`=B.`bank_id` AND A.`payment_invoice_date`=B.`maxdt`;
```

First you get the latest date using MAX() group by bank_id. Then make that as a sub-query. Create an outer query to inner join with the result you got on bank_id and max date.

Comment: Yes, the first issue got resolved. How can I apply the same query in CodeIgniter?

Comment: Your answer is working but can you help me how to use your code with my Codeigniter  query?

Comment: I'm sorry @NarendraVerma , I'm not familiar with Codeigniter

Comment: No problem, Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.